# Issue in creating an instance in rpsec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

In book.rb we have this code

```
tracked only: [:create], owner: Proc.new{ |controller, model| controller.current_user }
```

so when I create an instance of book model in the controller rspec it is generating an error

```
NoMethodError:
 undefined method `current_user' for nil:NilClass
```

How can I solve this issue . Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you add you whole rspec test?

Answer (score 0):

You could try and do something like this.

```
@user1 = FactoryGirl.create(:user, name: 'Jon', age: 20)
@book1 = FactoryGirl.create(:book, user: @book1)
```

This is that you are probably not creating your book instance with a user.